# My activity shows a white page when it should move to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having trouble how to apply the same layout as home_activity.xml.

When I tap the search icon on the bottomNavigationView, it shows me a blank page without bottomNavigationView.

As far as I debugged, it seems context.startActivity(intent1); does not work,
but don't know how to fix it.

error message is as follows

> W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@9a52ab7

codes are here:

SearchActivity

```
package com.example.android.instagramclone;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenu;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.android.instagramclone.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SearchActivity";
    private Context mContext = SearchActivity.this;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        setupBottomNavigationView();
    }

    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setBottomNavigationView: setting up bottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
//        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setUpBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationView);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

layout_bottom_navigation_view

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewBar"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            >

        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

BottomNavigationViewHelper

```
package com.example.android.instagramclone.Utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.bottomnavigation.LabelVisibilityMode;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.example.android.instagramclone.HomeActivity;
import com.example.android.instagramclone.LikesActivity;
import com.example.android.instagramclone.ProfileActivity;
import com.example.android.instagramclone.R;
import com.example.android.instagramclone.SearchActivity;
import com.example.android.instagramclone.ShareActivity;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "BottomNavigationView";

    public static void enableNavigation(final Context context, BottomNavigationView view){
        view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                //switch to different activities
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.ic_house: //ACTIVITY_NUM = 0
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent1);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: ");
                        break;
                    case R.id.ic_search: //ACTIVITY_NUM = 1
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent2);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: Search");
                        break;
                    case R.id.ic_circle:  //ACTIVITY_NUM = 2
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, ShareActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                    case R.id.ic_alert: //ACTIVITY_NUM = 3
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, LikesActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent4);
                        break;
                    case R.id.ic_android:  //ACTIVITY_NUM = 4
                        Intent intent5 = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent5);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

22:41 added

HomeActivity

```
package com.example.android.instagramclone;

import android.content.Context;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.android.instagramclone.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //What activity it's going through
    private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context mContext = HomeActivity.this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");

        setupBottomNavigationView(mContext);
    }

    /**
     * BottomNavigationViewSetup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(Context mContext){
        Log.d(TAG, "setBottomNavigationView: setting up bottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is Your problem here? You can't start new activity? You get error, or app continues to run with blank screen?

Comment: The app runs, but it continues to run with blank screen. I want SearchActivity to have the same layout as HomeActivity.

Comment: So You have 2 activities with same layout? Why not put logic from searchActivity into HomeActivity? Does You app start SearchActivity or not? Put more logging lines and post the output here so we can check better

Comment: Have you considered using one Activity that holds the BottomNavigationBar and a container, that holds a Layout and to change your two activities into Fragments?

Comment: >Dimness I have 2 activities with same layout. SearchActivity seems to start, but shows a blank page. I will put images later.

Comment: >procra Well since I kind of imitate this, I've never tried Fragments.  https://youtu.be/KMpcBT52_6o In this movie, my code is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your commments.
Now I know why and how to solve this problem.  "import android.os.PersistableBundle;" in SearchActivity was wrong. when I delete it, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise  context in the onCreate of Homeactivity.

```
mContext = Homeactivity.this;
```

or Just change this statement to

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(HomeActivity.this, bottomNavigationView);
```

Comment: Now I tried it, but it didn't work. I cannot use SearchActivity.this in HomeActivity.

Comment: sorry its my bad, updated, Its supposed to be HomeActivity.this

Comment: Ah no problem, but how is it different from my current code? my code has "private Context mContext = HomeActivity.this;"...

Comment: mContext is being initialised before onCreate()

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem. I put mContext in the OnCreate method of each of them and passed it to setupBottomNavigationView as a parameter, but nothing changed. I added the code to the end of my question.